# Symfony, put all pages behind login

Tags: security, symfony, routes

I am using the FOS userbundle, I want to put all my pages behind a login except of the fos pages. But I cannot seem te get it running. can someone help me configure it

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

        fos_userbundle:
                    id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

If I do

```
 - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The login, profiler etc doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
```

Comment: When I set it up like this, I get : This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: I have updated my answer. I switched `dev:` and `main:` rules. The problem is that the main rule match all requests and login is required.

Comment: Yes! exactly, didn't think of that one, it was the order of the firewalls. Thanks a million